# How to make the mobile menu full width

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to get the mobile menu full width, but doesn't seem to succeed.

```css
#menu-main-2 {
      background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
      padding-left:15px;
      max-width: unset;
      width: 100%;
}
```

[mobile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKsNF.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's already maximum width of its parent container? If you need it tight to edges you'll need to increase the containers width or `position absolute` the `ul` and then position relative the container.

If you want the main li in the ul to be horizontal across the top and only sub items to be drops then you'll need to flex the ul:

```
#menu-main-2 {
   display flex;
}
```

Comment: Will take a look at code when I'm on my pc in 5

Comment: Looks different from the screenshot? Have you sorted what you wanted? Looks full width to me, only issue is a fixed height is being added to the menu now so when I expand the 'clothing' sub menu it shows outside the container.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `width:100vw`

**Viewport** Width (vw) – A percentage of the full viewport width. 10vw will resolve to 10% of the current viewport width, or 48px on a phone that is 480px wide. The difference between % and vw is most similar to the difference between em and rem. A % length is relative to local context (containing element) width, while a vw length is relative to the full width of the browser window.

Comment: If the parent container isn't full width this could potentially cause other display problems though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to take full `width` you should try this:

```
#menu-main-2 
 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
```